# What is the max pay grade?

Tags: splatoon-2

What is the max % bonus on your Pay in Salmon Run?

You go up in that every time you win a run, but is there a roof on that somewhere?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Profreshional, 99-999 points, 200%-435% pay grade**

The highest rank title is Profreshional. When you attain that rank, you have a points gauge which appears to max out at 99, but it can in fact be increased all the way up to 999. The pay grade increases along with it, maxing out at 435%.

Since with each Salmon Run the gauge resets to 40 points if you are above that in Profreshional, it would take quite the marathon of consecutive hours to reach that high!

See the official guide for a breakdown of points and pay grade:

[image]